# Create visitor counter for each page

Tags: javascript

I just want to create a panel in which I can view how many visitors there have been for each page of my website.

I was thinking about doing a mysql database, with a table counter incremented at each visit via javascript.

But it's probably not the best way to do this, and I need advices..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would Google Analytics be an option? quick and easy to install and will give you visitor counts plus much more...

Comment: Which platform are you using for your front-end?

Comment: @hiren I start from scratch with an apache server, I'm not used to do websites so I don't know how to do. I want to do this little project mostly to train myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to include Google Analytics in your application. So it will track your page view and related data.

Feature of G.A: https://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/analytics/analytics/features/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Comment: And I guess I will be able to use Google Analytics API to display only wanted data on my 'panel' ?